# Export Expression Blend project in an accessible way?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, prototyping

I'm mocking up a wp7 app in Expression Blend. I would like to export it in an accessible way, so people without Visual Studio or Expression can view it. I know how to do it for [Sketchflow](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee426900.aspx), but it is also possible to do it for a Windows Mobile project?

Answer (score 0):

What format are you expecting to export it in?

You could create a "standard" Silverlight application which demonstrates your designs so people could see it in a browser.
This may or may not be appropriate dependent upon precisely what you want to show and how much your application requires phone specific functionality but could be an option.

Comment: I was hoping for something as awesome as the Sketchflow viewer, with support for feedback/annotations from clients.